# Grammar in ANTLR and the selected words

Tags: antlr

**EDIT**: I changed the example to explain better what I am trying to get.
This is my grammar:

```
INTEGER : ' int ';
LET : [a-z] ;
cchar : LET | '-' | ' ' ;
wor : cchar+; 
aaa  :  wor+ | wor* INTEGER wor* ;
```

aaa is the root. And writing eg.: 'xx int xx int'.
I would like to get a result: 'x x int x x i n t'. Only the first int should be catched, the next one should not give the "extraneous input" mistake but be splitted into letters.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Is this the whole grammar?  Or is there more to the grammar?

Comment: I changed it a little bit

Comment: Annabelle, I think we need more details. Is aaa the root rule ? What do you need to parse ?

Comment: Could you please read my question again? I edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to work as you wanted:

```
LET : [a-z];
INT : 'int ';

cchar : LET | '-' | ' ';
wor: cchar+;

int_string: INT;

aaa: (wor|int_string)+;
```

What this grammar says is that: alow me a word or an integer declaration, where integer is a declaration if it is 'int' followed by a space defined as a lexer item, everything else are words.

Now the following does not work:

```
LET : [a-z];
INT : 'int';

cchar : LET | '-' | ' ';
wor: cchar+;

int_string: INT ' ';

aaa: (wor|int_string)+;
```

After moving the space to parser rules instead of lexer rules, it fails to parse 'intt' for example, in fact any word that has an 'int' substring. It happens because the lexer part seems to read any occurence of 'int' as INT and even `wor` does not parse 'intt' as a string now, it tries to match `(wor int (cchar t))` and it fails for some reason not matching 'int' as separate cchars.

The first example's `wor` rule parses 'intt' as `(wor (cchar i) (cchar n) (cchar t) (cchar t))`. Which makes sense. The first example's grammar can't match it in the lexer phase because the space character required for lexer rule `INT` is not there in 'intt'.

Why has it done so? I'd think that it is because the lexer runs before the parser and what the parser gets is already the semantic equivalent. Even replacing the lexer rule `INT` with `'int'` in `int_string` in the second example yields the same behaviour as I expect antlr just generates a hidden lexer rule for that match. Not 100% certain though.

Tell me if this helps, if I come up with a way to fix the second case, I'll make an edit :)